# Discover properties within json schema using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

Using `newtonsoft.json.schema`, is there a way to find all (non-pattern) properties of an object (including those under properties, and those added through allOf, anyOf, etc.) and the fully resolved schema for each property?

I have looked through the documentation and source code, the only relevant pieces that could possibly help are in Infrastructure namespace and are internal (not public apis).

Is there any functionality build into `json.net`  that would do this for me out of box, or that could help me with implementing my own solution?

Comment: Are you looking for schema generation from a .Net object?

Comment: No, given a schema, I want to find non-complex properties of the object described by that schema

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "non-complex" and "non-pattern" in regard to a schema property?

Comment: I am looking to discover properties that have simple types, e.g. boolean, number, string, and not properties defined as "patternProperties" in the schema.

Comment: Whether a property has a simple type, or whether it is defined as a patternProperty, is entirely unrelated to each other: you can have "patternProperties" with simple types  (it just means that their names follow a regex pattern) and you can have "properties" with structured types (objects and lists).

Comment: Regardless, it's not possible, since one property can have two entirely different schemas depending on other properties (or it can have multiple schemas at the same time)

Comment: Doing this in a generic way to support all possible valid JSON Schema structures is a BIG ASK. Doing this for your specific use case, is possibly less complex a task. There's more complexity than you might expect, and it would slow down the validation process. Good luck =]